# Change Detail View on selecting tab of Master view in split view controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

I am new to ipad development. In my application i have created splitview like the below image. In this how can i call another detailview controller when tabbar on the left pane selection changes??

Please help me..

[image: My Splitview Screen]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply replace the VC at index 1 of the UISplitViewController's viewControllers property. Try something like-

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
     UIViewController* myReplacementVC = nil;
      if(viewController == VC1)
           myReplacementVC = myReplacementVC1;
      else
           myReplacementVC = myReplacementVC2; 

      NSMutableArray* arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:splitVC.viewControllers];
          [arr replaceObjectAtIndex:1 withObject:myReplacementVC]; //index 1 corresponds to the detail VC
          splitVC.viewControllers = arr;
          [arr release];
    }
```

Comment: I think u misunderstand my question... I need to change detail view when tab selected..

Comment: No issues, just replace buttonPressed by – tabBarController:didSelectViewController:. Edited my code.

Comment: You are right but there only the problem occurs.. I dont have class for tabbarcontroller since i ve created split view controller thus i cannot implement tabbarcontroller delegate methods... Am i right??? Where can i put this action????

Comment: Okay, so you have not used a UITabBar? Then are the tab-like things buttons or images?

Comment: No... I ve used tabbarcontroller in split view controller... I replaced navigation controller (Master Pane) by tabbarcontroller...

Comment: Then all you need to do is set the delegate of the `UITabBarController` to the class where you create it. Make the class implement `UITabBarControllerDelegate' & then you can add the method i have used in my answer.

Comment: Sorry i din create tabbarcontroller programmatically.. I created it using IB. So i dont have any class for tabbarcontroller. I implemented  tabbarcontroller delegate in split view's root view controller but nothing happens :( I think u ll get irritation by getting this answer :(

Comment: @itdeeps let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2836/discussion-between-akshay-and-itdeeps)

Comment: In IB, select the UITabBarController, in the outlets panel, connect 'delegate' to the File owner. Then implement the method in the answer in the class that's the file owner.

Comment: I tried it but no change... Pls check if u dont mind http://www.cx.com/dl/?sn=ad142fb0ba18...

Comment: @Akshay: hi, me to having the same issue. Me too have implemented an app as in the fig above, and on the master view i have programatically created UITabbarController and having 4 views in it, I implemented this in Appdelegate file. So where should I implement the above code?

Answer (score 0):

This addressed the issue for me:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MultipleDetailViews/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009775-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2

and with Storyboards

http://www.raywenderlich.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=1546